# command line tools installed but terminal says they're not

Tags: macos, mac, xcode

Running OS X 10.9 trying to upload MacPorts following their [guide](http://guide.macports.org/#installing.xcode.mavericks)

```
Jadam$ xcode-select --version
xcode-select version 2333.
```

so I have Xcode on the computer, but when I enter in `xcode-select --install` I get the following return in the terminal:

```
xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools
```

Immediately followed by a, pop-up, update error message:

```
"The xcode-select command requires the command line in 
developer tools. Would you like install the tools now?"
```

with the options "Get Xcode", "not now" & "Install". When I choose install, a "Finding Software" loading bar runs through but then ends with the following message:

```
"can't install the software because it is not currently 
available from the software update server"
```

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907576/xcode-is-not-currently-available-from-the-software-update-server) clearly did not work for me.